# OpenSSL text max size?

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, php-openssl

Using OpenSSL I have created a basic encrypt/decrypt class. My goal is to encrypt text (JSON) to be sent over http to/from a remote web_service. 
*(yeah, I know I could use https instead, but there're some technical constraints not to use it in this case)*

```
class Crypt {
   static private $default_method = "aes-256-cbc";

   public static function doEncrypt($text_to_encrypt) {
      // ...some preparation stuff here
      $result = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($text_to_encrypt, self::$default_method, $seckey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
      return $result;
    }

   public static function doDecrypt($encrypted_text) {
      // ...some preparation stuff here
      $result = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypted_text), self::$default_method, $seckey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

      return $result;
   }
}
```

I have conducted many tests using texts of different sizes and it works fine. But ...where is the limit?

**My doubt:**

Where is the limit of `text_to_encrypt` max size? In my tests I got it work properly with texts up to 100Mb. With bigger texts I got http time-out error ...but that's due to my current test-server limit. I know I can modify it, or I can look for more powerful servers which will process faster.

In case I had unlimited process capacity, where would be the bottle-neck? What would set the limit of the `text_to_encrypt` max size? Will encrypt/decrypt process fail at some point? Will be PHP the limit?

This is how I test:

```
define("_MIN_SIZE", 10000); // size of text, in bytes
define("_MAX_SIZE", 250000);    // size of text, in bytes
define("_SIZE_INCREASE", 1033); // size incresase for tests, in bytes

echo '<h2>Test encrypt/decrypt</h2>';
for($i = _MIN_SIZE; $i < _MAX_SIZE; $i = $i + _SIZE_INCREASE){
    $string = generateRandomString($i);
    $encstr = crypt::doEncrypt($string);
    if($string != ($descstr = crypt::doDecrypt($encstr) ) ){
        echo "<p style='color: red'>ERROR!".strlen($string);

    } else {
        echo "<p style='color: green'>OK ".strlen($string);

    }
    echo '</p>';
}
echo '<h2>Done!</h2>';

function generateRandomString($length = 25) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-.,_:;<>çÇ´`ñÑáÁàÀéÉèíÍìÌïÏóÓòÒúÚùÙüÜ¿?=)(/&%$·"!ªº@|¡+[]{}€';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

> Note: I know there are some missing parts regarding the full data
>   workflow. I.e. Authentication, as pointed in a comment, seckey
>   and iv generation and management, etc.). But for a sake of simplicity I
>   haven't shown the whole process in the question. My concern is about
>   where is the size limit for encrypting strings in PHP using OpenSSL.

Comment: You can't encrypt more text than you can store (plain + cipher), obviously. Other than memory limitations, why do you think there is any limits? And you can get around memory limitations simply by encrypting using a piecemeal or streaming approach.

Comment: The "technical constraints" for not using HTTPS will be easier to solve than developing your own solution that is actually secure.  Your ciphertext isn't even authenticated.

Comment: @James K Polk you're right. I can't encrypt more text than I can store. This was my first thought when I asked myself which would be the text size limit. But then I realised that I was not sure if this PHP constraint (how big strings can PHP manage correctly?) was the limitation factor, or wether there was any other not-obvious one.

Comment: Right @Luke Joshua Park. In the code sample there is no actual authentication. Anyway the whole process it is (code not shown, I use regular WebService authentication; but for a sake of simplicity I haven't shown the whole process in the question). My concern is about where is the size limit for encrypting strings in PHP using OpenSSL.

Comment: @MarcM I'm not talking about authenticating users. I'm talking about authenticating your ciphertext. In your current code, there is no way for you to tell if the ciphertext has been modified in transit.  This is why you should be using HTTPS.

Comment: Again, you are right @Luke Joshua Park But I can't use https. Webservices will be installed at customers computers, and we won't be able to maintain properly and updated a big bunch of SSL certificates sparsed over several computers (hundreds of them). Is there a way I can use https without having to be pending of SSL certificates?

Comment: Run your own CA or use Let's Encrypt.  Both require little maintenance if you set it up correctly.  At the end of the day, the effort involved to get TLS/SSL working, even in a situation like that, is far less than the effort involved to securely implement your own encryption and key handling.  I highly recommend you don't do what you are doing now.

Comment: Hi ... Did u everr get yr answer ? What is the max size that we can encrypt - max lenght of a string ? Also do u mind sharing your class code  ... i would like to learn ...if u cant i understand ...